# Execute code when app goes off-screen on Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

I am currently trying to implement a feature on my current project that will allow me to execute some code when the app goes off screen.

This is for security reasons as I want to push a route that requests the User's PIN number before allowing them back into the app.

My HSBC banking app implements a feature like this so it must be possible.

I have completed this for Android and it works a charm, I used: https://pub.dev/packages/screen_state

This package is Android only and I would like to replicate the same functionality for iOS, or, preferably, use an alternate method that will work on both platforms.

I have researched it online and can't find anything, I must be missing something obvious.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WidgetBinding Observer instead of this package

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {...}

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }


    @override
    void dispose() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
      super.dispose();
    }


    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
      if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
        // Here put your code you want to execute
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and clean example, I have just searched it and it looks like just the thing, thanks!